# Cloud Functions for Firebase error: "400, Change of function trigger type or event provider is not allowed"

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

When I run `firebase deploy` I get this error message:

```
functions: HTTP Error: 400, Change of function trigger type or event provider is not allowed
```

Comment: Did you previously deploy function `getWatsonToken` as triggered by an HTTP request instead of a database event?

Comment: Bob, I originally wrote getWatsonToken to trigger from auth onCreate. I deployed it but I never ran it.

Comment: The answer by @creative... explains the issue and a solution.

Comment: In the Firebase Console for Functions, I have getWatsonToken, under 'Event' it says 'user.create', and the number of executions is zero.

Comment: @Thomas: the Google Cloud Functions tag already exists as shown by Bob's edit. Proper tagging for questions such as yours is `google-cloud-functions][firebase]` (or whatever part of Firebase you're using).

Answer (score 88, accepted):

### TL;DR

```
firebase functions:delete yourFunction // this can be done via the Firebase Console as well
firebase deploy
```

### Explanation

Basically, Cloud Functions expects the same trigger for every function all the time, i.e. once it is created it has to stick to its original trigger because every function name is connected to a specific trigger. The trigger can therefore only be changed by *deleting* the function first and then creating it again with a different trigger.

This can now be done easily by using the **`functions:delete`** command:

```
firebase functions:delete yourFunction
```

The [documentation features more advanced use cases](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#delete_functions) as well.

### Old solution

Solution of this is basically commenting or cutting out your function and then saving the Functions file and deploying. The function will get deleted in Firebase, but after that you can insert/uncomment your function and it will deploy just fine again. This error occurs when you take a function and change the type of trigger that it uses, i.e. HTTP, database or authentication.

*Firstly cut it out*

```
/* exports.yourFunction = someTrigger... */
```

*And then, after **deploying** ("firebase deploy") replace your trigger*

```
exports.yourFunction = anotherTrigger...
```

Comment: Umm, wouldn't it make more sense for Firebase to have a delete button for functions in the console?

Comment: From reading another StackOverflow question, Firebase Console doesn't have a 'Delete Function' button (unlike Google Cloud Functions) because 'firebase deploy' overrides anything you do in the console, i.e., you could delete a function in the console but if you don't delete the function from your project, the next time you run 'firebase deploy' the function will appear in the console.

Comment: OK, I followed your instructions and everything worked as you said. But the new function doesn't execute. I see it in the console with the 'Event' as 'ref.update  /userLoginEvent', which looks right. When I login I see in the database '/userLoginEvent' changes. But the function doesn't execute, and no Watson token appears.

Comment: I'm getting no error messages, on 'deploy' or in the console when I login as a different user.

Comment: Oh, wait, it just worked when I tried it again! Cool! Thanks!

Comment: That should be definitely documented in firebase documentation.

Comment: Firebase now added the functionality to delete your functions from the cli like this: `firebase functions:delete yourfunction`. More info [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#delete_functions)

Comment: I'm getting this error even if I didn't edit the function it's complaining on

Comment: You can also try to update the firebase with "npm install -g firebase-tools". For me that solved the problem

Answer (score 10):

For those who stumble upon this in the future, the Cloud Functions console now offers a delete button.  [image: screenshot of the right hand side's "more" options]

Comment: Thanks, a smooth solution

Answer (score 1):

You can also go to the Cloud Functions panel in the Google Cloud Platform console and delete your function from there. After that you can upload the function normally from firebase CLI. Not sure why they don't have a delete function option in the firebase console.

Answer (score 0):

Even better, one has the option to copy an existing function in Google Console now. You only have to change the name and the trigger section, everything else will be the same as you old function.